# Parameterized Option Type

Tags: scala

I understand that Options are parameterised i.e. Option[T] but how do I specify a nested parameterised type e.g. `Option[Node[T]]`?

I have this class definition

```
class Node[T <: Serializable] private(val path: String, val data: T, val parent: Option[Node[T]] = None) {
...
}
```

and when i construct it as new `Node[String]("/", "Test", None)` scalac chokes as it expects Node[String], not Node.type. I then tried

```
new Node[String](path = "/", data = "Test", parent = None[Node[String]])
```

But None does not accept parameters

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the exact error you're getting in each case

Comment: It probably "chokes" because the constructor is private, not because the type is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So None is always None, without parameter, as somebody explains.

Another pitfall is that String is not a subtype of Serializable, but of java.io.Serializable:

This works fine:

```
scala> class Node[T <: java.io.Serializable ] (val path: String, val data: T, val parent: Option[Node[T]] = None) { }
defined class Node

scala> new Node("/", "")
res19: Node[String] = Node@4b520ea8
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that Scala's Serializable is not the same as java.io.Serializable. I must find out more about this ..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine: you just have to wrap a present value in `Some()`. `Option` can be represented as `Some` or `None` for present and not-present. If you want the value to be absent you can call it with:

```
parent = None
```

`None` does not take parameters (since it represents an absent value) and it's also an object, i.e. only one instance exists. But it has a type parameter `Nothing`, which *is a subtype of any other type*, so it works just fine in place where an `Option[Node[T]]` is expected.

If you want a value present you have to wrap it in `Some`, like this:

```
parent = Some(new Node[String]("/", "Test", None))
```